# how to change similar ng-repeat values for each angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i want to change ng-repeat values separately, from shown single input text box,
i'm trying to bind inputbox to label, but all values binding together, can u please tell me how to change only selected div values..
[Working DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/w4OOYz6JMxoJdmZJF4nH?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('AddCtrl', function ($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.items = [];
    
    $scope.add_New = function (index) {
        var itemhtml = '<div ng-click="select()" class="content">//click here first// <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{$index + 1}}. {{item.name}}</div></div>';
        var item = $compile(itemhtml)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('drop')).append(item);
     };
     
     $scope.add = function () {
         $scope.items.push({ 
             name: "hi"
         });
     };

     $scope.select = function(){
         $scope.showItem = true;
     }
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */
body{
    width:1000;
}
.add{
    width:300;
}
.show{
    width:400;
    float:right;
}
.content{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="AddCtrl">
        <button ng-click="add_New($index)">add Again</button>
        <div id="drop" class="add">
        </div>
        <div ng-show="showItem" class="show">
            <div ng-repeat="item in items">
                {{$index + 1}}.<input type="text" ng-model="item.name">
            </div>
            <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>

         </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked into directives or components in 1.5?

Comment: @CallumLinington no.. Can u tell me how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave it a shot, tried my best to understand what you wanted, got to [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/zZHKTc3gOWnufVVEd0Yz?p=preview) point.

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('AddCtrl', function ($scope, $compile) {

    var id = 0;

    $scope.sections = [];

    $scope.addItem = function(section) {
      section.items.push('hi');
    }

    $scope.select = function(){
      $scope.showItem = true;
    }

    $scope.addNewSection = function(){
      id++;

      var newSection = {text: 'Section '+id, id: id, items: []};
      $scope.sections.push(newSection);
    }

});
```

And the html.

```
<body ng-controller="AddCtrl">
    <button ng-click="addNewSection()">Add Section</button>


    <div ng-repeat="section in sections" class="content">

        {{section.text}} 

        <button ng-click="addItem(section)">Add</button>

        <div ng-repeat="item in section.items track by $index">
            {{$index}}. <input type="text" ng-model="item.name">  
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: obviously correct.. but no values entering into input box if we type something in to it,, and if i select section div have to show entered values in a certain corresponding div .. can u check my code once again pls...

Comment: you wrote in the code that have to push 'hi' value in input text box.. but no value showing in result and no value binding anywhere ... can u pls explain me how to get the result...??

Comment: thank you very much.. you done a great job.. i got extact result what i was expected is?? if i use **section.items.push({});** instead of using **section.items.push('hi');** :) tnx alot

Comment: Glad i could help :)